# Sign across resistor, circuit with diodes and fuse

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, fuses

[image]

Okay, so I had shown with arrows the signage in question, shouldn't it be other way? Otherwise KVL

$$ V_s = I_{fuse} (50) + 1.4 \color{red}{+} I_{fuse} R_{L} $$ isn't correct...

Also, in the problem, $ I_{fuse} $ shouldn't exceed 0.1 A, otherwise fuse will "blow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Apologies, I misread the polarity they'd given. Yes, this is wrong. The plus and minus signs on Rl are the wrong way round. Other than that, their working is correct.

*No. As long as you're consistent, and you stick with the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention), it doesnt matter what direction you choose to represent your current. In this case, everything in their working seems correct.*

Comment: also, since you're here, can you also tell how was $V_o$ determined here: https://i.imgur.com/l6mUf3O.jpg, I mean, if you do KVL across circuit it will yield $V_o = -10V - 10V, no?

Comment: By Vo do you mean the voltage labelled v=0? This circuit is a bit convoluted, as you can very easily see just by looking at it that a) you can split this into two unconnected circuits and b) the "v=0" is effectively connected straight to ground, so of course v=0. It might help if you had a copy of the original question.

Edit: are those blobs supposed to be fuses?

Comment: no it's just short diodes (when on). Even if there's no current, there's voltage, isn't it? Ohm's law V=iR doesn't always stand, like here: https://i.imgur.com/5e6TcLG.jpg  (curren't doesn't flow on either side of Vd2)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/48tnwdX.jpg Isn't similar to Voltage across Vd1?? On the negative side, it's connected to ground + it's on same node as -10V voltage supply and +10V V.S. Yet it only the +10V VS that matters...

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Do you have a copy of the original question?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/oskoZbn.jpg B) part

Comment: Ok I get it. Theyre trying to see if the diodes are conducting or not, by solving the circuit assuming they are conducting and then seeing which direction the current is flowing. If it's flowing from anode to cathode then it is, otherwise it isnt and they have to resolve the circuit. It's hard to tell exactly what you're confused about with this question, I suggest you post another question on stackexchange about it.

Comment: I already said, Vd1. It shouldn't be like that. Vd1 on negative side shares nodes with +10 and -10V supplies...

Comment: Do you mean the cathode of D1? If so, then yes it does. What's wrong with that? Ground is defined as V=0. All that a voltage supply does is set the voltage between it's cathode and its anode as whatever the supply voltage is, in this case +10V. This means that the node at the top between the resistor and the voltage supply is at 10v, and the node at the bottom between the other resistor and the other voltage supply is at -10v.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66129/discussion-between-jack-and-beb00).